# Homotopies on Other Categories

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've just started reading Dieck's book on algebraic topology, and in Section 2.2, Dieck talks about homotopies on other categories, such as $TOP(2)$, $TOP^K$ and $TOP_B$. I've noticed something though.

The morphisms of all three categories are continuous maps between topological spaces that satisfy some special property. Dieck defines a homotopy on each category as a homotopy $H:X\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ between morphisms $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ such that for any $t\in[0,1]$, $H_t:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism in the category.

I'm wondering, for any category $C$ where the morphisms are continuous maps between topological spaces that satisfy some special property, can I define homotopies on $C$ analogously? Because if so, this opens up a whole new side to algebraic topology that I haven't seen before.

Comment: Sure you can, what exactly stops you from doing that? But the real question is: how useful such thing is?

Comment: Well, uniform homotopy, Lipschitz homotopy, and proper homotopy all have applications in geometric topology and have been useful, for instance, in the classification of open manifolds.

Comment: Yes. But that's the question. The question is: why the proposed generalization is useful?

Comment: Thank you guys for these answers. These definitions actually took a lot of reading and searching online to understand. It's just mindblowing that an idea as abstract as homotopy can be abstracted even further.

Comment: Model categories are a further way to abstract the notion of homotopy. Quillen wrote a book about them called "Homotopical algebra."